# 1c bitrix Каталоги

Tags: php, битрикс

Создал новый раздел в каталоге(Фаерволы), подскажите, кто знает, как вытащить товары с другого раздела(Серверы) в новый по ID? Заранее спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можете уточнить свой вопрос? Вы хотите перенести товары из одного раздела в другой?

Comment: @NikolajSarry Хочу скопировать с одного в другой(тот, который создал)

Comment: Штатной опции копировать по-моему нет. Поставьте бесплатное приложение "Инфблоки. Инструменты" (вроде так называется) Антона Долганина. Тогда при отметке галочками нужных товаров добавится опция "Копировать"

Comment: @NikolajSarry Ответы - в ответы. Хорошее приложение.

Comment: @AK не было времени дать нормальный ответ поэтому отписал быстро комментарием :)

Answer (score 1):

В Битрикс: Управление сайтом нет штатной опции копирования элементов. Установите бесплатное приложение ["Инфоблоки, инструменты"](https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/asd.iblock/) Антона Долганина.

После этого переходите в список элементов:

1. Отмечаете нужные элементы галочками
2. Под списком нажимаете кнопку "Действия" и выбираете "Добавить привязку к другому разделу".
3. Появится кнопком со списком выбора разделов. Выбираете нужный раздел.
4. Нажимаете кнопку "Применить".

После этого элементу привяжутся к еще одному разделу. С помощью этого решения можно переносить элементы в другой раздел или даже в другой инфоблок.

Скрин в подсказку: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3456892/b4f8e2da1a3a5ade7990e234e7480fa0